# How can an angle be negative?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, triangles

How can be angle be negative like `sine(-60) , cosine(-50)` ? 
Which quadrant do they fall if we have the negative angles ? I dont see any negative angles in full circle of 360

[image]

Comment: $-60^{\circ}$ is not distinguished from $300^{\circ}$ in this case, for example.

Comment: further more $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Comment: fyi angles can be complex or even matrix, now get somebody explain that cause I cant.

Comment: @Arjang The most important is here that the way people explain small things with great explanations. I am loving it . The first comment explained me everything but still I am reading all comments to see the opinions of all expertise :)

Comment: $-60°-k\,360°,\cdots,-780°,-420°,-60°,300°,660°,\cdots,-60°+k\,360°$ all describe the same angle.

Comment: Not sure anyone here really answered OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angles increase positively by increasing counter clockwise.  So a negative angle is one that starts in a *clockwise* direction.  60 is the angle 60 degrees *above* the x-axis so -60 is the angle 60 degrees *below* the x-axis.

Angle measures are considered cyclic and any angle $x$ is equal to $x \pm 360$. So $-60$ is the same thing as $300$.

In particular 180 = -180.  Also convenient are -90 = 270.  And of course 0 = 360.

====

Believe it or not you will encounter situations where you need to consider angles of 720 degrees.  These are simply 0.

Sometimes you'll have to do something like sin(x + y) or cos(x - y) and have things like x = 135 and y = 243.  It's useful to know that 125 + 243 = 368 = 8 and 135 - 243 = -108 make sense.  (Actually -108 = 108 clockwise is far more intuitive than 252 degrees is.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\sin (330°)=\sin (-30°)
$$
In other words: the positive angles are  counterclockwise, the negative angles are clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

For a negative angle, you simply need to rotate in the other direction (i.e., clockwise instead of anti-clockwise).

This means that for an angle of $-40^\circ$, you end up at the same point (and with the same values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ as an angle of $320^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Negative angles are connected to an `orientation` on the circle, just as negative abscissae are connected to a `direction of travel` on a straight line: once you've decided what is the positive direction of travel (from left to right, or from right to left), the straight line becomes an (`oriented`) `axis`, and points on this axis can have a positive or negative abscissa.

Similarly, once you've decided what is a positive rotation on a circle (clockwise or counterclockwise), it becomes an `oriented` (or `trigonometric`) circle. Remember an angle, in a sense is but a curvilinear abscissa on a circle with radius $1$.